# Objective-C: instance variables out of scope in debugger

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, inheritance, pointers, scope

I have a superclass and a subclass, both of which define instance variables.

Rough outline of superclass:

```
/* GenericClass.h */
@interface GenericClass : NSObject {
    /* some variables */
}
@end
/* GenericClass.m */
@implementation GenericClass
    /* ... */
@end
```

Outline of subclass:

```
/* SpecificClass.h */
#import "GenericClass.h"
@interface SpecificClass : GenericClass {
    NSMutableString *str;
}
/* SpecificClass.m */
#import "SpecificClass.h"
@implementation SpecificClass
- (void)aMethod {
    //Debugger reports str as out of scope
    str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
    //Works fine:
    self->str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
    //Doesn't compile as I haven't defined @property/@synthesize:
    self.str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
}
```

When I am using classes that inherit directly from NSObject, one doesn't need the self-> pointer. Note that there is no object with the name str defined in the parent GenericClass. 
So, my question is, why is str out of scope when not referenced as self->str? The code in itself works, but I can't read the variable with the debugger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GDB is not an Objective-C compiler. The compiler knows about things like lexical scope within Objective-C methods, but GDB does not. It does, however, understand local variables.

In Objective-C, every method has an implicit `self` parameter passed to it when it's called. So when you look at `self->str`, GDB is interpreting that like it would interpret any other local variable evaluation.

When you try to evaluate `str` on its own, GDB will look for a local variable called `str` and, not finding one, reports that it's not in scope. This is not an error; this is the expected behavior.

Comment: This is a good clarification of how the GDB works, thanks! But there is one thing still confusing me. I have variables defined in the superclass; let's call one NSMutableString *superstr. A reference to "superstr" on its own in the implementation of SpecificClass works fine. But attempting to access a variable "str" defined in SpecificClass.h doesn't work in the debugger without using self->. How does GDB find an inherited variable, but not one defined in this class's own header? If I'm not using inheritance, this also works just fine. It seems like a bug in XCode

Comment: Try `po str` and `po superstr` in the Debugger Console window (⇧⌘R). If those give the same results, the problem has nothing to do with Xcode (which is likely).

Comment: Oddly enough, po str and po superstr work fine in the console, as do po self->str and po self->superstr. It's only in the visual debug UI where the str variable without self-> reports being out of scope when moved over with the mouse, but read/write operations in the code work just fine. I'll log it as a bug with Apple. Meanwhile I'm using self-> everywhere (although I'd prefer not to) so that I can visually debug.