# Why is my variable out of scope?

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSMutableArray defined in my AppDelegate class:

```
NSMutableArray *devices;
```

I populate the array from a class in the didFinishLaunchingWIthOptions method:

```
Devices *devs = [[Devices alloc] init];
self.devices = [devs getDevices];
```

The getDevices method parses a json string and creates a Device object, adding it to the array:

```
NSMutableArray *retDevices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[jsonDevices count]];

for (NSDiectionary *s in jsonDevices) {
    Device *newDevice = [[Device alloc] init];
    device.deviceName = [s objectForKey:@"name"];

    [retDevices addObject: newDevice];
}

return retDevices;
```

I then use the AppDelegate class's devices array to populate a tableView. As seen in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Device *d = (Device *)[appDelegate.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.label.text = d.deviceName;
```

When the tableview is populated initially, it works. But when I scroll through the list, and the cellForRowAtIndexPath is executed again, d.deviceName throws an error because it has gone out of scope.

Can anyone help me understand why? I'm sure it has something to do with an item being released... but... ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're leaking the retDevices array, which isn't even declared properly (you forgot the *). Similarly in the second code block you appear to be leaking the devs object.

Comment: You're also leaking each newDevice inside of the retDevices array.

Comment: The missing * was an oversight on my part while copying the code over. My app actually has the * at that declaration. Should newDevice be released at the end of the loop?

Comment: Why do you assume *scope* has anything to do with this?

Comment: @chuck if I put a breakpoint in the method and try to view the value of deviceName it tells me "out of scope".

Comment: @Chu: That's just a quirk of how the debugger works, not a problem with your program. See this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566086/objective-c-instance-variables-out-of-scope-in-debugger/1566843#1566843

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is indeed a problem with memory management, answering these questions should lead you to an answer:

- Is `deviceName` declared as a `retain` or `copy` property by the `Device` interface declaration?
- Is `-deviceName` synthesized? If not, how is it implemented?
- Is `devices` declared as a `retain` property by the app delegate class's interface declaration?
- Is `devices` synthesized? If not, how is it implemented?

Of course, it might not be a problem with memory management. It would help a lot if you were to provide the actual text of the error message and any provided backtrace.

Comment: deviceName was declared as @property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) NSString *deviceName;  If I change it to retain, at what point do I need to release it?

Comment: When its owner dies, i.e., the `Device` object. Put `[deviceName release], deviceName = nil;` in `Device`'s implementation of `-dealloc`.

Comment: ok, adding retain to the delegates devices declaration seems to have fixed this. Can anyone help me understand *why*? Without retain, is the memory being 'released' by itself at some point (a type of garbage collector?) Why does it work for the first iteration, but fail later when the list is scrolled?

Comment: Its owner was the `NSDictionary` in `jsonDevices`. When that dictionary went away, it took the `deviceName` string with it. The `Device` instance needs to retain it to stake its claim of ownership. Then, when the dictionary goes away, `deviceName` still has an owner: your `Device` instance. When that instance dies, it needs to release the `deviceName` string to relinquish its claim of ownership. If there are no more owners, `deviceName` then dies as well.

Comment: Why did the `NSDictionary` go away? Because it was owned by an `NSAutoreleasePool`. These pools assume temporary ownership of an object with the expectation that whey will be drained at the end of every run loop cycle, if not sooner. Sending an object an `-autorelease` message is a way to transfer ownership to the autorelease pool. When that pool is drained, it releases everything in it.